# C# Filling excel cells row by row

Tags: c#, excel

Hey I am trying to create this program that sends the input into an excel file and im stuck on how to store the input on the next line.

So far I am able to get the string from my textboxes into the second row of excel under the headers, but I want to give the user the ability to add in multiple rows.

```
oXL = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            oXL.Visible = true;

            oWB = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(oXL.Workbooks.Add(""));
            oSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)oWB.ActiveSheet;


            // -- Workstation Information --
            oSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "UserName";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Workstation Name";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 3] = "Manufacturer";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 4] = "Model";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 5] = "Serial";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 6] = "CPU";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 7] = "RAM";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 8] = "OS";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 9] = "Version";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 10] = "Microsoft Office";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 11] = "Recommendations";
            oSheet.Cells[1, 12] = "Comments";

            oSheet.get_Range("A1", "L1").Font.Bold = true;
            oSheet.get_Range("A1", "L1").VerticalAlignment =
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

            string[,] saNames = new string[500, 500];

            saNames[0, 0] = txtUsername1.Text;
            saNames[0, 1] = txtWorkName1.Text;
            saNames[0, 2] = cbxManufac.Text;
            saNames[0, 3] = cbxMachType.Text;
            saNames[0, 4] = txtModel.Text;
            saNames[0, 5] = txtSerial.Text;
            saNames[0, 6] = txtCPU.Text;
            saNames[0, 7] = cbxRAM.Text;
            saNames[0, 8] = cbxOS.Text;
            saNames[0, 9] = txtVersion.Text;
            saNames[0, 10] = txtMcstOffice.Text;
            saNames[0, 11] = txtRecomend.Text;
            saNames[0, 12] = txtComments.Text;


            oSheet.get_Range("A2", "L1000").Value2 = saNames;

            oWB.SaveAs("discoSurvey");
```

This is what my Save button currently looks like. I want to create an add button that will let them keep adding information to this excel sheet. How do I move them to the next row?

Comment: have you tried using a `For` loop?

Comment: @MacroMan I was thinking of doing that im just not sure how to well do it

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of what your UI looks like? It might make more sense to store these entries into a DataTable in memory and then print the DataTable to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

Hm,

you need to find the first empty row in the Excel file to add your next line, right?

so you can use the suggested for loop to search the next empty row, and then use the found rowindex to insert your values.

i just saw this more clearly..

```
        string[,] saNames = new string[500, 500];

        saNames[0, 0] = txtUsername1.Text;
        saNames[0, 1] = txtWorkName1.Text;
        saNames[0, 2] = cbxManufac.Text;
        saNames[0, 3] = cbxMachType.Text;
        saNames[0, 4] = txtModel.Text;
        saNames[0, 5] = txtSerial.Text;
        saNames[0, 6] = txtCPU.Text;
        saNames[0, 7] = cbxRAM.Text;
        saNames[0, 8] = cbxOS.Text;
        saNames[0, 9] = txtVersion.Text;
        saNames[0, 10] = txtMcstOffice.Text;
        saNames[0, 11] = txtRecomend.Text;
        saNames[0, 12] = txtComments.Text;
```

though i do not like the 500x500 array - all you have to do is to query your array for null in a row and use that index to insert values.
but you need to hold your array in a way to not redefine it all the time.. put it to a field maybe.

Comment: haha sorry the 500x500 was just me messing around and experimenting,  I reverted it back to lesser values